# Trouble setting up tableView cell inset

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

Okay so, I'm creating a tableview and its respective cells programmatically. I have two issues that I am unable to resolve.

I am not sure how to set an inset so as to create an adequate amount of space between the edges of the cell and the text. I am new to swift and so I may not be correct, but is there a function I can utilize?

Here is the code I'm using to generate the tableview and its cells:

```
//
//  HashtagController.swift
//  InstagramApplication
//
//  Created by jshbrmn on 2015-03-05.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 2gen. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit

class HashtagController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

  var model:ModelData!
  var cellCount = 0
  var currentCell: UITableViewCell!

  var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CherrySwash-Regular", size: 25)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red:27.0/255, green: 145.0/255, blue: 114.0/255, alpha: 1.0)]
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return model.quoteItems.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cat = Array(Array(model.quoteItems.values)[cellCount])[0] as String

    if(cat == model.categoryName) {
      println(model.categoryName)
      println(model.quoteSelection())
    }

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = Array(Array(model.quoteItems.values)[cellCount])[0] as? String
    cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26, green: 34, blue: 48, alpha: 0.0)
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell?.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(red:26.0/255.0, green: 34.0/255.0, blue: 48.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Light", size: 14.0)
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping

    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = Array(model.quoteItems.keys)[cellCount]
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26, green: 34, blue: 48, alpha: 0.0)
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:32.0/255.0, green: 178.0/255.0, blue: 139.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Light", size: 14.0)

    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26, green: 34, blue: 48, alpha: 0.0)

    var bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell?.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
    cell?.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell?.layoutIfNeeded()
    cellCount++
    return cell!
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    var currentLabel = currentCell.textLabel?.text
    var currentAuthor = currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text

    model.quote = currentLabel!
    model.author = currentAuthor!
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    model = (self.tabBarController as CaptionTabBarController).model

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.frame         =   CGRectMake(0, 10, view.frame.width, view.frame.height);
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26, green: 34, blue: 48, alpha: 0.0)
    //tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle(rawValue: 0)!
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
  }
}
```

This is what the list currently looks like:

[image]

For each cell, there needs to be more padding at the top, bottom, left and right.

Also, as an aside. Is there an appropriate way (ie. not so hacky) of removing the left inset on the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your cell property called preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins to false

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

Them you just have to set your cell layoutMargins to zero

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

Comment: I placed this in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function and it didn't change anything...could it be because it is set up for multilines and wordwrapping via - `cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0` and `cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 15, 50, 0);
```

But I thought this can help you a lot , check this out [Dynamic Table View Cell Height and Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

Comment: i added this in the `viewWillAppear` function and the result was the inset of the entire tableview and not within the individual cells